# Debug memory usage during py.test run

Tags: python, unit-testing, memory-leaks, pytest

We have test which passes if run stand alone. But if we run all tests, `py.test` fails since no memory is left.

My question: How to display the memory usage of the py.test process before and after each test?

This way we could be able to find the tests which have memory leaks.

Other solutions are welcome, too.

We run Python 2.7 on linux.

The root of the memory problem was solved: Django changed Queryset iteration to load all instances. In my case millions :-) See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#queryset-iteration

But I am still interested in the general question.

Comment: Is it a python project or you are just writing the tests in python? Also, are you sure it is because of memory usage?

Comment: @khajvah this a project written in Python.

Answer (score 3):

`pytest-xdist` plugin gives you `--boxed` option, where each test is ran in own subprocess.

You that to work around your test, and also to track resource usage (not sure how atm).

Finally, it is quite possible that it is interaction of your tests and not a single test alone that piles up memory. You can use `-k` selector or `pytest-random` plugin's flag `--random` to verify my conjecture.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-random